# How to Refresh Code every 30 Seconds ActionScript3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer

I have a piece of XML that goes out and grabs data. That data is being updated every so often. I want the user to be able to see the updated data by creating a way to reload it every x amount of time.

How do I use the timer to do this in Actionscript 3?

Comment: I think it's been downvoted because the use of Timer is something that can be understood easily with Google. SO is not intended to be used to save your time: google and read the documentation before post the question. I think this is the reason

Comment: @Sr.Richie sorry but to me that just sounds like arrogance, stackoverflow is a community where we help eachother with our simple or complex questions. All these arrogant downvoters are achieving are deterring people from this community. I for one will upvote this question and answer it as I believe this is a legitimate question. Also for the downvoters some advice, when you downvote, leave a comment explaining why, or if you think this question is too simple and doesn't warrant an answer on stackoverflow, then simply do not answer the question.

Comment: @Taurayi I don't know what of my comment could sound arrogant. You ask for an explanation, I gave you my interpretation. Best regards

Comment: @Sr.Richie sorry I didn't mean you personally, I meant those who downvote for the reason that you said in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a basic timer set up (UNTESTED CODE):

```
var timerRefreshRate:Number = 30000; //Miliseconds between timer refreshes (30 seconds)
var fatherTime:Timer = new Timer(timerRefreshRate, 0);
fatherTime.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, refreshXML);
fatherTime.start();
function refreshXML(evt:TimerEvent = null):void {
   //put your code to load the xml here
}
```

If I inadvertently created any bugs in my code above, or if you want to understand the Timer class more, there's also a good Timer tutorial here:
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3timer/